# Tested VueJS file problems

Tags: vue.js

I have this simple file and using `http-server` it does not work. Please help. **NOTE** that I have a proper `<head>` of the HTML page .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>VueTester</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
        },
      })
    </script>

    <div id="app">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if i understand you right, you just have a simple `HTML`-file and want to use `vue` in it.

In this case you just have to reorganize your code like this and it should work:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: { message: 'Hello Vue.js!' }
    })
</script>
```

If i missunderstood you just tell me and I try to edit it.